# ViewPager navigation buttons

Tags: android, button, swipe, pager

I already have the two buttons "left" and "right" in my xml-pager file..
I want to set them: when i click on "left" button the page swipe automaticlly to left and when i click on "right" button it goes automatically to right.. can someone give me the code to put in my activity file? thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To go the next/previous page use something like the following:

```
private void nextPage() {
    int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrent();
    int totalPages = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();

    int nextPage = currentPage+1;
    if (nextPage >= totalPages) {
        // We can't go forward anymore.
        // Loop to the first page. If you don't want looping just
        // return here.
        nextPage = 0;
    }

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPage, true);
}

private void previousPage() {
    int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrent();
    int totalPages = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();

    int previousPage = currentPage-1;
    if (previousPage < 0) {
        // We can't go back anymore.
        // Loop to the last page. If you don't want looping just
        // return here.
        previousPage = totalPages - 1;
    }

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(previousPage, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joseph..
Im really new to android programming so im sorry for this question but where i got to put this code?

Comment: Put it in your UNO.java, and replace `viewPager` with `mPager`.

Answer (score 1):

For android.support.v4, you can use the following:

```
ViewPager pager;
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);       
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Have a veiwpager adapter class like this:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        switch(pos)
        {
            case 0: return WelcomeFrag1.newInstance("Page 1");
            case 1: return WelcomeFrag2.newInstance("Page 2");
            case 2: return WelcomeFrag3.newInstance("Page 3");
            case 3: return WelcomeFrag4.newInstance("Page 4");
            case 4: return WelcomeFrag5.newInstance("Page 5");
            default: return WelcomeFrag1.newInstance("Page 1");
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }       
}
```

And finally have two methods nextPage() and previousPage() like this:

```
private void nextPage() {
    int currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
    int totalPages = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

    int nextPage = currentPage+1;
    if (nextPage >= totalPages) {
        // We can't go forward anymore.
        // Loop to the first page. If you don't want looping just
        // return here.
        nextPage = 0;
    }

    pager.setCurrentItem(nextPage, true);
}

private void previousPage() {
    int currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
    int totalPages = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

    int previousPage = currentPage-1;
    if (previousPage < 0) {
        // We can't go back anymore.
        // Loop to the last page. If you don't want looping just
        // return here.
        previousPage = totalPages - 1;
    }

    pager.setCurrentItem(previousPage, true);
}
```

Take note: I am using getCurrentItem() to get the index of the current page